# automating telnet session in windows is not working

Tags: windows, scripting, automation, telnet

Hi I have created a file `temp.txt` with the the content as below

```
root
root123
ls -lrt
exit
```

and then I am excuting the below command in dos

```
c:\>telnet machine_ip < temp.txt
```

Output is

```
Welcome to the Microsoft Telnet client
Escape character is 'ctrl+]'
C:\> Telnet>
```

How to automate the telnet session in windows with this method. I cant use any other exe(putty.exe) or tool to do this. I have to use the available things in windows xp. Suggest me also if any other way is there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can pass the **`username`** and **`password`** to `telnet` program from a `text file`.

You can create a **`vbs script`** and use *`sendkeys`* to pass `username` and `password`.

Create a `batch` script which starts a `telnet` session of a box and then call the `vbs` script from the `batch` script using

```
CSCRIPT //NoLogo //B "C:\Path\to\Script>script.vbs"
```

Hope this helps!